# Load a file of Ruby code

Tags: ruby, oop

Having the following files:

```
# ./app.rb
require_relative 'container'
require_relative 'contained'

# ./container.rb
class Foo
  def initialize &block
    puts block.call
  end
end

# ./contained.rb
Foo.new do
  "Hello, world!"
end
```

We can test and see everything's okay from a console:

```
$ ruby ./app.rb
Hello, world!
```

But I would like to simplify **contained.rb** by removing `Foo.new do` and `end`, keeping just the content of the block, by modifying **app.rb**.

In this quest, I came to this result:

```
# ./app.rb
require_relative 'container'
require_relative 'contained'

Foo.new do
  eval File.open('contained.rb').read
end

# ./container.rb
class Foo
  def initialize &block
    puts block.call
  end
end

# ./contained.rb
"Hello, world!"
```

With the same result:

```
$ ruby ./app.rb
Hello, world!
```

However I am not very proud of this code, mostly because of the `eval` method.  Is there a best practice in this kind of case?  What would you do?
Thanks for sharing your light.

Comment: I would leave it at the first example. The second, apart from using eval, introduces some magic to the code that could have you or another developer scratching their heads in a few weeks/months/years.

Comment: What helped you to decide the use `#eval` ?

Comment: I agree. It's not worth the effort. It's wiser to keep the code as in the first example. Thank you, @a-fader-darkly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you want to read from a separate file must be that you want to separate it from the main code and you want to occasionally change it. That category of things belongs to what would be called *configuration*. It is common these days to write that as a YAML file and read into Ruby using a yaml library.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @sawa!  I see more clearly now.